# Not getting any ajax response

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, ajax

I am wokring on coding standard and  need to replace **echo** with **$this->getResponse()->setBody($relatedBlock)** But below code is not working for me. with echo it working perfectly.

```
public function showpopupAction(){

$this->loadLayout();

if($this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_head')){
    $relatedBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_head')->toHtml();

    $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','text/xml',true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($relatedBlock);

}
```

Comment: Hi, what response do you receive? 200 and 0bite ? Probably script fall down some where later? If you make echo - it will show your xml immediately (with std output) , but when using response - it will be rendered when response object is rendered. Can you copy complete action code?

Comment: @AlexSilenko thanks you are right simple `return` do the trick for me. You can put as answer.

Comment: You can check what you have in response body
in lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php
public function outputBody()
    {
        $body = implode('', $this->_body);
        echo $body;
    }
Probably body is rewriten on some observer, etc..

Comment: @AlexSilenko i got the solution. it is simple after `$this->getResponse()->setBody($relatedBlock); return;` the trick will stop executing  the other script

Comment: Cool. That;s what I meant

Comment: @AlexSilenko can you put these as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what you have in response body in

```
lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php 

public function outputBody() { $body = implode('', $this->_body); echo $body; }
```

Probably body is rewriten on some observer, etc..